# UITextField Form inside UIContainerView Returns nil When Text Exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uicontainerview

Hierarchy: NavigationController (Root) --> SignupViewController (2nd Level) --> SignupTableView (3rd Level). SignupViewController contains a ContainerView that embeds the SignupTableView. The SignupTableView contains the fields you see in the image.

I define

```
    @property (nonatomic,strong) SignupTableViewController *tableViewController and
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"signupFieldSegue"]){

    SignupTableViewController *destination = (SignupTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    self.tableViewController = destination;
    }
```

}

inside of SingupTableView.

An IBAction button press inside of validates the fields in the `UITableView` inside the `UIContainerView`, but the value returned from the `UITextField`s inside the `SignupTableViewController` is nil. I tried `self.tableViewController.usernameField.text` and defined

```
- (NSString *)getUsername {
     return _usernameField.text;
}
```

Both solutions return nil when text does exist. Any way to access the text?

[image: Screen Image]

Comment: Where is `_usernameField` declared?

Comment: Would it be possible to share a minimized version of your project? It's hard for me to understand the relationships between your view controllers.

Comment: Great! You're welcome. I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've written in your question, it seems like your container view shares the screen with the main (parent) view controller. Regardless, you first need to make sure that the validation methods are executing before the view controller containing your form is deallocated.

In you parent view controller, you should keep a reference to the segue's destination view controller. That way, the validation from the parent view controller can easily retrieve data from the view controller in the container view.

First, declare a property in your parent view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) FormViewController *formViewController;
```

Then, in `prepareForSegue:sender:`, set that property to the destination view controller of the segue.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(nonnull UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"signupFieldSegue"]) {
        FormViewController *destination = (FormViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        self.formViewController = destination;

        // continue preparing for the segue...
    }
}
```

Then, in your validation methods, use that property to access the `UITextField` values. Here's an example using your `getUsername` method, assuming `FormViewController` has a `usernameField` property:

```
- (NSString *)getUsername {
    return self.formViewController.usernameField.text;
}
```

Again, keep in mind that none of this will work if your form view controller gets deallocated before you attempted to access its text fields.

Comment: Edited my post to provide more info ... The subview inside the container view still is visible as shown in the picture. I press Sign Up, and the IBAction method is invoked. Stepping through through the code, accessing any of the fields with getUsername() or self.textfield.text both return nil. No clue why.

Comment: @jried Did you try my solution?

Comment: Yes I did. The image is the screenshot of the error that still remains. Only thing you did differently was (weak, nonatomic) vs my original (strong, nonatomic) for the tableviewcontroller.